# How many kinds of "Security Models" are there?

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have heard about "*principal based security*", "*role based security*", "*component centric security*", and in .NET, I get to know that the Code Access Security (CAS) is kind of a "*origin based security*".
So are there any other security models? And what technically do they mean? Could someone give me some explanations, or point me to some reference?   Many thanks.

Comment: I just wrote an answer for another question that I think might be applicable here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177361/modelling-a-permissions-system/3177578#3177578

Answer (score 1):

[Code access security](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/UB_CAS_NET.aspx#Functions%20of%20Code%20Access%20Security) is more of a function used by .net to comply to a security model.  A security model itself is a loosely defined term for [general security concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security_model).

For example, role based security or role based access control is a security model to define access to a resource based on a user's role.  Although, this is all just a smaller portion of the whole security component that needs to be considered as a part of development.  This can be a big help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/default.aspx

But you can also look into more generalized security concepts such as the Comptia Security + certification for beginners and the CISSP through ISC2 for a bit more advanced security knowledge for a heuristic approach to security.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia defines a [computer security model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security_model) as

> A computer security model is a scheme
>   for specifying and enforcing security
>   policies. A security model may be
>   founded upon a formal model of access
>   rights, a model of computation, a
>   model of distributed computing, or no
>   particular theoretical grounding at
>   all.

As you might imagine with a definition that broad there are many types of computer security models. Rather than re-listing all of the various models here it'd be easiest to take a look at the mostly complete [computer security model category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_security_models) from Wikipedia. Finally, Wikipedia also provides a [computer security portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Computer_security) linking to a multitude of computer security topics.

Aside from that MSDN has some excellent articles on [securing .NET applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkytk30f(v=VS.71).aspx) available. They also provide what appears to be a pretty good [security tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288469(VS.71).aspx).