# What's the cleanest way to allow access to a webpage only through a redirect

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, servlets, web-deployment

I'm developing a website for an university homework, and I'd like to forbid access to some pages who should be accessed only by some users when specific links are clicked.

Suppose users should not access to secretAccountsList.jsp page, but only administrators can, and they can only access it by clicking the specific URL which calls `sendRedirect` to secretAccountsList.jsp.

I know that this could be achieved somehow with sessions and forms, but it seems quite mechanical to me, is there any cleaner and direct way?

Comment: What you think,should be a cleaner approach than using resource filters(web filters)?Several examples are available over internet,and please produce an example of what you have tried to do.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177361/modelling-a-permissions-system) SO post?

Comment: Mechanical? I can't imagine of any cogwheels in Java code :) Anyhow, this question is two-fold: 1) Restrict access to administrators. 2) Restrict access by referrer. Those completely unrelated requirements need to be researched and solved individually. That will make things easier, such as finding already answered questions. One bite at a time.